# Javascript giving parameters to inner function

Tags: javascript

So my basic setup is this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var indices = [-1, -1, -1];
    while (index == -1) {
        // Do Stuff
        index[i] = newIndex;  
    }       
    var press = function() { alert(i); };
    new control({press: press});                
}
```

Now when I press the each of the new controls instead of getting alert(0), alert(1) and alert(2) I get alert(3), alert(3) and alert(3).
I can kind of understand whats going on. Now my question: how can i pass the different indexes to the function as I intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because closure variable `i`, the solution is to create a private closure for each loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var indices = [-1, -1, -1];
    while (index == -1) {
        // Do Stuff
        index[i] = newIndex;  
    }       
    var press = (function(myvar){
        return function() { alert(myvar); };
    })(i);
    new control({press: press});                
}
```

Comment: For learning purpose it's better not calling the closure parameter `i` as it's confusing. IMHO.

Comment: Thanks it works now :). Now another question what actually happens: (function(a))(b) means that b is passed as parameter .... oh wow now i got it myself: It's an anonymous function which is passed parameter b ?!

Comment: probably you should read about closures https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope should give you a start

Answer (score 1):

Use closure:

```
var press = (function (x) {
    return function () {
        alert(x);
    };
})(i);
```

This way the current `i` value is saved in a safe place, a private function.

Note that declaring variables (with `var`) inside loops are not standard, you should declare the `press` variable outside the loop.